# Angular 9 extend ServiceProviderComponent with providers

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular9

I have a ServiceProviderComponent whose only job is to provide a Service.
I want to extend this ServiceProviderComponent by an other Component (HelloComponent) so i can use the Service in it and its children.
How is it possible to accomplish this without to call super(); in HelloComponent constructor with that service as argument?
I have tried to inject the Injector and to provide the service with Injector.create() but it doesn't work.

I have created a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t6s3cq) - demo.
In hello.component i want to use the in ServiceProviderComponent provided instance of the BASE_TEST_TOKEN injection token but always the global instace is used.

Is it even possible to have something like a ServiceProvider component i can extend?

**UPDATE 1**
I have updated my [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tvoang) with a directive. I want this directive also to use the Service instance of the hello.component.
How can i get this done?

Comment: I know this does not answer your question, but why do you want to create service provider component instead of simply injecting the needed services directly?

Comment: @marcel i want to have multiple instances of the service in different components but i don't want to have the 'provide' lines in each of this components

Answer (score 2):

Although it's a bit difficult to understand what you want, but I believe it is possible by using the `Injector` and creating a new one in the constructor with the `Injector.create` method.

Although the `.create` method only allows so called `StaticProviders`, you can inject other services by using the `deps` property with `useFactory:

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gdzw5p?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent extends ServiceProviderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() name: string;
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.name = this.testService.test();
  }
}
```

<sub>The stackblitz shows a different `@Directive` config, but that's because the stack is based on angular 8. With angular 9 you can (and must) use an empty directive. Anyways when you extend a component/directive, whatever you have inside the base decorator will not be read/extended</sub>

```
@Directive()
export class ServiceProviderComponent {
  protected testService: BaseTestService;

  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    injector = Injector.create({
      providers: [{
        provide: BASE_TEST_TOKEN,
        useFactory: (...deps) => new TestServiceService(),
        deps: []
      }],
      parent: injector
    });

    this.testService = injector.get(BASE_TEST_TOKEN);
  }
}
```

--

For your update you unfortunately have to extend the service component from your directive and inject the injector and pass this along in the super call:

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qdrwb8?file=src/app/my-directive.directive.ts)

<sub>On a side note, it feels like you are working in anti pattern of what angular predicates. You are trying to solve something which should either be solved in another way, or not solved at all. From your question I can't really see what your ultimate goal is with all of this</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your example is almost what i need. I have one more problem, i have Updated my post with an updated version of your example. Can you please tell me how to accomplish this?

Comment: Thanks for the update. My final goal is that i have multiple components which have an async initialization, all of them need an own http request to receive data. But they can have dependencies on each other so i am trying to have a service where i can control my own lifecycles of the DataSource initialization of all components. These compoments are created dynamically by a directive and the constellation of these components can appear multiple times. So i want for each instance of this constellation an own instance of my service

Comment: HI all,
The Injector.create( is deprecated.

Comment: @Laszlo the function itself is not deprecated, just the signature has changed to only allow an object with options. I've updated my answer to reflect this

Comment: You are true, correct!